# 'Options' object has no attribute 'get_all_field_names'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

In my `django-admin`, I am trying to make a `model` non-editable.

So, I am `overriding` a method `get_readonly_fields` of `admin.ModelAdmin`.

`Here is my Code`

```
@admin.register(SMSTemplate)
class SMSTemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['title', 'json', 'note']
       formfield_overrides = {
       JSONField: {'widget': PrettyJSONWidget }
    }

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        return self.model._meta.get_all_field_names()
```

But I am facing an error. I am pasting the error here.

```
'Options' object has no attribute 'get_all_field_names'
```

Any Idea why ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is probably because you are using django 1.10. `get_all_field_names` [was deleted](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/#migrating-from-the-old-api) in this version. Use `get_fields`

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    return [f.name for f in self.model._meta.get_fields()]
```

Or for full compatible version

```
from itertools import chain

def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    return list(set(chain.from_iterable(
        (field.name, field.attname) if hasattr(field, 'attname') else (field.name,)
        for field in self.model._meta.get_fields()
        # For complete backwards compatibility, you may want to exclude
        # GenericForeignKey from the results.
        if not (field.many_to_one and field.related_model is None)
    )))
```

Comment: I am getting this error --> Type Error : hasattr(): attribute name must be string

Comment: @AdilMalik Are you copied my answer or just used it as example?. Because this code taken from docs and it works. Show me where you got this problem?